# Is it possible to set the return email address based on user input?

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

So if the user enters their e-mail as part of the form that's submitted, and the administrator gets a notification, could that notification's "reply to" field be from the e-mail that was submitted?

This would be convenient because if the person notified wanted to reply to the user, they'd just hit reply, instead of having to copy/paste the e-mail into the e-mail field.

Currently notification "from e-mail" field is always set to the e-mail address that's set in Admin / Email Config / Return email address for auto generated emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can add the field in the Reply to Email field in your notifications template. For example I use {email} which is the field I have set up to capture their email.

[image: Notifications screen grab]